# Php creating strange session cookie value

Tags: php, session, cookies, roadrunner

I'm not sure it has any influence but just for some context, the application powered by a roadrunner server. Cookie payload is extracted at event loop and the session's cookies are computed just while reading response headers into the roadrunner psr response object.

So, the issue proper:

Yesterday, while testing session functionality, I observed that desired content was getting written to the session, but unfortunately wasn't getting picked up after what should be a redirect flow i.e. GET->POST->GET (session data gets lost here). Further debugging got me into the current state I need an extra pair of eyes on. The session file is no longer written to anywhere!

I have checked `C:\wamp64\tmp` but the sess_cookie-name is not there. I have tried using `ini_set`, `session_save_path` and the `save_path` key, all to no avail. I've restarted the server and my system. **Strangely enough**, another file gets written to the configured directories after each request. But since it doesn't bear the name of the cookie sent/supposed session id, it just keeps creating new ones, thereby defeating the aim of data persistence. This is the class controlling session:

```php
namespace Suphle\Adapters\Session;

use Suphle\Contracts\IO\{EnvAccessor, Session as SessionContract};

use Suphle\Services\Decorators\BindsAsSingleton;

#[BindsAsSingleton(SessionContract::class)]
class NativeSession implements SessionContract
{
    public const FLASH_KEY = "_flash_entry",

    DEFAULT_SESSION_KEY = "suphle";

    protected string $sessionId = "";

    public function __construct(protected readonly EnvAccessor $envAccessor)
    {

        $this->safeToStart();
    }

    /**
     * Avoid "session already started" errors. The superglobal must wait for this to be called before it can be accessed. Otherwise, all data from preceding request will be lost
     */
    protected function safeToStart(array $sessionOptions = []): void
    { // redesign this to receive external input instead of being called from the constructor?

        $isSafe = session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE // sessions are enabled but none exists

        && !headers_sent();

        if (!$isSafe) return;

        session_id($this->getSessionId());

        session_start(array_merge(["save_path" => __DIR__ . "/sxc", // remove

            /*"use_cookies" => 0,

            "use_only_cookies" => 1,*/

            "use_strict_mode" => 1
        ], $sessionOptions));var_dump($this->getSessionId(), $_SESSION, $_COOKIE);
    }

    protected function getSessionId ():string {

        if (!empty($this->sessionId)) return $this->sessionId;

        return $this->sessionId = $_COOKIE[self::DEFAULT_SESSION_KEY] ??

        session_create_id();
    }

    public function getCookieData ():string {

        return implode("", [
        
            self::DEFAULT_SESSION_KEY. "=". $this->getSessionId(). ";",

            "path=/; HttpOnly;",

            "Max-Age=". $this->envAccessor->getField("SESSION_DURATION"). ";"
        ]);
    }

    public function setValue(string $key, $value): void
    {

        $_SESSION[$key] = $value;

        session_write_close(); // moves data from memory to file and saves
    }

    public function getValue(string $key)
    {

        return $_SESSION[$key];
    }

    public function allSessionEntries(): array
    {

        return $_SESSION;
    }

    public function getOldInput(string $key)
    {

        return $this->getValue(self::FLASH_KEY)[$key];
    }

    public function setFlashValue(string $key, $value): void
    {

        if (!$this->hasKey(self::FLASH_KEY)) {

            $this->resetOldInput();
        }

        $flash = $this->getValue(self::FLASH_KEY);

        $flash[$key] = $value;

        $this->setValue(self::FLASH_KEY, $flash);
    }

    public function hasKey(string $key): bool
    {

        return array_key_exists($key, $_SESSION);
    }

    public function hasOldInput(string $key): bool
    {

        return $this->hasKey(self::FLASH_KEY) &&

        array_key_exists($key, $this->getValue(self::FLASH_KEY));
    }

    public function resetOldInput(): void
    {

        $this->setValue(self::FLASH_KEY, []);
    }

    public function reset(): void
    {

        $_SESSION = [];

        session_destroy();
    }
}
```

The question is who could the culprit be? Where is it manufacturing that weird cookie value from? Mind you, the `isSafe` block never runs